# Firebase Cloud Functions returns INTERNAL Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In the below code, while I'm trying to insert data into firebase Firestore, the data gets inserted but on returning promise, it returns error as INTERNAL Error.  Hera is the console logged Error

```
Error: INTERNAL
at new f (error.ts:66)
at y (error.ts:175)
at O.<anonymous> (service.ts:231)
at tslib.es6.js:100
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
at r (tslib.es6.js:71) "INTERNAL"
```

> The Code in Cloud Functions (index.js)

```
exports.addNewBook = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('books').add(data.book)
        .then((doc) => { return doc })
        .catch((error) => { return error });
});
```

> The Client Function invoking the Cloud Function (Client Function)

```
const addNewBooks = (formData) => {
   bookData = {
      no: formData.bookNo.value,
      name: formData.bookName.value,
      author: formData.bookAuthor.value,
      publisher: formData.bookPublisher.value,
      librarian: formData.librarianName.value
   }
   console.log(bookData);
   const addBooksToDb = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addNewBook');
   addBooksToDb({
         book: bookData
      })
      .then(doc => {
         console.log(doc, doc.id)
      })
      .catch(error => {
         console.log(error, error.message)
      });
}


$("#addBookModalForm").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   addNewBooks(this);
   this.reset();
});
```

> Error logged on Cloud Functions on console.log() in index.js

```
    addNewBook
    Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded 
        at isArrayLike (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:11333:31)
        at keys (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13307:14)
        at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4900:21
        at baseForOwn (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
        at Function.mapValues (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13400:7)
        at encode (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:179:18)
        at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:38
        at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4905:15
        at baseForOwn (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
        at Function.mapValues (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13400:7)
```

What is the reason for throwing an **INTERNAL** Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promise returned from `add()` probably rejected and generated an error.  If you don't take care to send a specific, known response to the client, you could see an error on the client.

Since we can't see the exact inputs and outputs (you are just showing variables here), and the log output, we have no way of knowing exactly what happened, so you will have to debug this to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Can you please say some possible reasons for a promise to get rejected?

Comment: You should log the error in your function to find out what happened.   In fact, you should be logging everything so you can see for yourself that all values are exactly what you expect.  This is how you debug a function.

Comment: I've posted the error logged on the CF Console, but couldn't figure the problem.  I've just implemented a simple add function, for that why the call stack size gets exceeded.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add logging to the server side.  It should be plainly clear the values of all the variables you're working with **in the function**, since that's where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Found Out the Error, actually on returniing promise after adding the document, I've returned the raw data from the firestore rather than returning a snapshot.  Thank You for your help.